# sitefinity update view from action method

Tags: sitefinity

I am using this form to post data to the controller once the data is saved I wanted to display this Success view but I am getting a 404 page not found. Any idea why I am getting this error?
View

```
@using (Html.BeginFormSitefinity("Save", "Preference", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "preferencesForm" }))
{
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4 float-center">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

controller

```
 public ActionResult Save(PreferenceViewModel model)
        {
            SaveData(model);
            return View("~/Mvc/Views/Preference/Success.cshtml");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your code hit the Save method? I don't see it marked with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Also, if this is your Preference widget, then you can simply use this:

```
return View("Success");
```

Sitefinity will look for success.cshtml in the correct folder.